# Using anonymous methods inside of a delayed task inside of a loop

Tags: c#, lambda, async-await, task

I have the following -

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    var firstTask = DoSomething(...);

    var task = anotherTask.ContinueWith(
        (t) => ProcessResult(i, t.Result));
}
```

Problem being that the value of i passed into ProcessResult seems to be the value when it starts, not the value of the iteration when it is created.

What is the best way to protect against this?

Comment: Why are you using `ContinueWith` instead of await? As for `i` your lambda captures the *variable* not the value of the variable. Reading `i` will return whatever `i` contains when you actually read it - when the call to `ProcessResult(i,..)` is actually executed. This is the expected behavior by the way. Using `await` will fix this by getting rid of the lambda *and* simplify your code

Comment: To chain the tasks. These can be long running, whereas would await would suspend the current thread.

Comment: No it won't.  `await` *awaits*, it doesn't block. It's the equivalent of `ContinueWith`, not `Wait`. It makes chaining a *lot* easier* because it doesn't require lambdas and captures.

Comment: Anyway, you can pass a state parameter to `ContinueWith` and access it inside your lambda. This was replaced by `await` and direct access to variables after .NET 4.5

Comment: Thanks. I'm new to Task/await. I think i need to go read up again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to capture the value of `i` into its own variable.

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    var count = i;

    var firstTask = DoSomething(...);

    var task = anotherTask.ContinueWith(
        (t) => ProcessResult(count, t.Result));
}
```

Example:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    var a = i;
    var task = Task.Delay(0).ContinueWith((t) => a.Dump());
}
```

This outputs something like:

```
0
2
1
4
3
```

But this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    var task = Task.Delay(0).ContinueWith((t) => i.Dump());
}
```

Outputs:

```
5
5
5
5
5
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a temp variable inside the loop; in your current code  you are capturing the *variable `i`, not the value*, which means that when the continuation tasks are finally executed the loop has already finished and `i` is `N-1`.

```
 for (int i = ...)
 {
     var temp = i;
     var task = anotherTask.ContinueWith(t => ProcessResult(temp, t.Resume));
 }
```

Comment: Or use `await` instead of `ContinueWith`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos yes, but the question is about why the code behaves the way it does, not if this is the best way to do the job.

Comment: Thanks! I take it the compiler / garbage collector can handle the loop moving on and the variable won't be disposed?

Comment: @user2036256 First of all, the variable can not be disposed because it's not a disposable object. Second, why would it be any different from your current code? You seem to be conflating *scope* and *lifetime* of a variable. They are most certainly not the same; your loop variable `i` goes out of scope too and it doesn't seem to blow up your code. Why would `temp` be any different?

Answer (score 2):

A lambda that uses an outer variable actually captures the variable, not the value stored in it. That means that as looping proceeds, the value you would read from the captured variable also changes.

You can fix this by using a temp variable inside the loop. Your code would be a lot cleaner though if you used `async/await` instead of ContinueWith and lambdas, eg:

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    //...
    var result=await thatOtherAsyncMethod(...);
    ProcessResult(i, result));
}
```

In general, you can avoid capture problems by copying the loop variable into a variable defined inside the loop's scope.

This fixes the problem because the temporary variable exists only inside the loop's body. The lambda is *also* created inside the loop's body and captures a local, unchanging variable:

```
for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
{
    var temp=i;
    var myLambda = new Action(()=>MyMethod(temp));

    //This runs with the local copy, not i
    myLambda();
}
```

An even better way though, is to *avoid* captures and pass the loop value as the state parameter to `ContinueWith`, eg:

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i)
{
    //...
    var task = anotherTask.ContinueWith(
                               (t,state) => ProcessResult((int)state, t.Result),
                               i);
    //...
}
```